# Change button size programmatically

Tags: android, button, size

I already checked existing thread for a solution. The answer was always:

setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(100, 100)

So I tried, but as I push the button my application crashes:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button btn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btn.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(100, 100));
        }
    });
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong ? Thanks !

Comment: the app crashes and what is the stacktrace?

Comment: make sure you have `button1` in `activity_main` layout and please post logcat

Comment: I surrounded the line in the onClick Method with a try & catch block but the exception is not thrown or at least it doesn't print my specified tag to logcat. But here is a part of what's in logcat: http://i.imgur.com/fAkdMIl.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the exception that you get (ClassCast); you have to tell where the View it is sitting on. E.g. if your Button is inside a RelativeLayout:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lyt = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
btn.setLayoutParams(lyt);
```